# Adding a RESTful, OAuth API on top of Craft

Tags: plugin-development

I’m currently considering options for a project that will require a standard sales site, commerce features and a user database. The user database will require a web frontend and an API for communication with a mobile app (read and write).

My dilemma is whether it makes sense to consider Craft for all three components, which will give us all the benefits of a unified system, or to split the user database into a separate project where we could take advantage of something like Laravel Passport, which seems like the obvious option for efficiently building a secure API.

The [HTTP Messages](https://github.com/airtype/craft-httpmessages) plugin looks useful but doesn’t appear to deal with authentication at all and preexisting options for Yii/Craft OAuth appear limited to nonexistent. I get the sense that Craft 3/Yii 2 would make life easier, but waiting for a stable Craft 3 release isn’t possible.

Has anyone had any experience developing a secured API on top of Craft? If so, what route did you take and would you do it again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: yes I have, I used OAuth 2 and I would absolutely do it again.

I wrote up my experience in general terms [here](https://angell.io/blog/what-i-learned-creating-an-api-in-craft) but essentially it boiled down to two plugins, one on each site: one acting as the server and another as the client.

I used [`league/oauth2-server`](http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/) for the server and then tied in directly to the [Dukt OAuth plugin](https://dukt.net/oauth) for the client, but in retrospect it would’ve been simpler just using [`league/oauth2-client`](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client) for that.

For transforming data like the Element API does I used [`league/fractal`](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/) and then to get proper request behaviour I used [`zendframework/zend-diactoros`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-diactoros).

Essentially I think this sort of thing is perfectly feasible in Craft, due to plugins being so flexible you can load whatever libraries you need and go nuts. Craft 3 could simplified things somewhat with [Yii Modules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html) as I’m guessing you could package up the whole API code as a module, but it shouldn’t be necessary.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That’s great – thanks! I’ve been looking at the league/oauth2-server package so it’s a relief to hear that you had success using that with Craft. It sounds as though ‘Craft all the things’ is the way to go.

Comment: @DomStubbs ha, yes I'm a massive advocate of that approach!